# Joomla 2.5 -- get sef url from itemid

Tags: joomla, sef

How can I find the correct SEF url of an Menuitem, based on its ID?

```
$link = JRoute::_( $menus->getItem( $id )->link.'&lang='.$languages[ $code ]->sef, true );
```

delivers something like:

```
http://localhost/<path>/component/content/?view=featured
```

but what i want is the url generated from the menu, which is:

```
http://localhost/<path>/<lang-sef-code>/<path>
```

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution for the problem I had.

```
$languages = JLanguageHelper::getLanguages('lang_code');
foreach ($associations as $code => $id ) {
    item = $menus->getItem( $id );
    $link = JRoute::_( 'index.php?lang='.$languages[ $code ]->sef.'&Itemid='.$item->id );
}
```

this delivers:

```
http://localhost/<lang>/<path-to-link>
```

I noticed that when dealing with SEF URLs than the order in which vars are given to the JRoute::_() method are decisive. I hope to help somebody who got some problems with this too.

Greetings

philipp